# trying to scroll to position of anchor with offset

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to scroll down to the position of an anchor tag with an offset, but am having problems. I've got this:

```
$('#about-menu > li > a').click(function(){
    var anchor = $(this).attr('href');
    var position = anchor.offset();
    $(document).scrollTop(position - 100);
});
```

But in the console, I get:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object #meet has no method 'offset'
```

Answer (score 0):

Do the following:

```
$('#about-menu > li > a').click(function(){
    var position = $(this).offset().top;
    $(document).scrollTop(position - 100);
});
```

The way you did was trying to call `offset()` method from the `href` attribute (which didn't exist, that's why the error) of the anchor, not from the anchor itself.

Also, you have to use the `.top` property from `offset()`, which will point the top offset of that anchor.